# How do I gsub this string using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

Ok this is rather embarrassing but I have this string:

```
>> t1
=> ["name: Big Lebowski\n"]
```

Then I want to replace the entire line with `""`

```
>> t2 = t1.collect{|n| n.gsub("/^name.*$/", "")}
=> ["name: Big Lebowski\n"]
```

I get the same thing. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put your regular expression inside a string, which obviously won't work.

```
>> t2 = t1.collect{|n| n.gsub(/^name.*$/, "")}
=> ["\n"]
```

If you also want to get rid of the newline, use the `m` regex modifier.

```
>> t2 = t1.collect{|n| n.gsub(/^name.*$/m, "")}
=> [""]
```

Answer (score -3):

That's because you're using "gsub" in you block instead of "gsub!" - as the last one modifies the target. Try:

```
t2 = t1.collect{|n| n.gsub!("/^name.*$/", "")}
```

Comment: Why do I need to bang it if I'm adding it to another variable?

Comment: This is not the reason, but that OP uses a string instead of a regular expression.